# Event Tracking Code

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking

Does anyone see anything wrong with this event tracking code:

```
    <div class="columnTwo">
        <div style="padding-bottom:7px;"><span class="pe">p.</span> <span class="numberBot">800.809.7000</span><br></div>
        <div><span class="pe">e.</span> <a href="mailto: saleswebinquiries@callcarenet.com" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact', 'Sales', 'Footer'])"><span class="salesTeam">email our sales team</span></a></div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to track the button click.
Any help much appreciated!
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code on a testing site and it worked flawlessly. I used GA Debugger to analyze the http request being sent, and confirmed that it was received by looking at the real-time report for Google Analytics.

Are you sure you're sending it to the correct property and that GA is loaded before the event is happening?

Comment: Yea it's going to the right domain and I have GA loaded on the site on every page. Is it possible it's something in the backend of how I set it up? Im'm tracking an event with the different fields lining up with the fields in the code

Comment: Could you post that code? I don't think that's the issue, though. Did you look at the real-time report after you clicked the event? Anything show up?

Comment: Yea I've checked in the backend of Analytics and still don't have anything going on in my reports. It shouldn't be anything in the site tracking code for sure.

Comment: Could you share the site?

Comment: http://www.callcarenet.com/main/lets-talk.php I have code on the "email our sales team" on the sidebar and footer.

Comment: Yep, everything looks good to me. In the profile you are viewing the account under, does it have any filters applied to it? Like, for instance, the IP address you're working from? You've looked at the Real-time > Events and nothing?

Comment: I actually do have filters set up that I forgot about, could I get you to click once on each?

Comment: Done, just clicked each of them a few times.